# Sum of Previous months Sales with MDX

Tags: mdx

The below query works okay.

```
With Member PyMonthSales as
    SUM(PARALLELPERIOD([Date].[Calendar].[Month], 1),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])    

select 
{PyMonthSales} on Columns,
[Date].[Calendar].[Month] on Rows
FROM
(
Select {
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[5], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[4]
} on Columns
From    [Adventure Works]
)
```

But I just want one Grand total. So I removed the rows, on the above query

```
With Member PyMonthSales as
    SUM(PARALLELPERIOD([Date].[Calendar].[Month], 1),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])    

select 
{PyMonthSales} on Columns
FROM
(
Select {
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[5], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[4]
} on Columns
From    [Adventure Works]
)
```

This is where the problem starts. Returns null. Any assistance would be great. 
Thanks for your time.

Naz

Comment: Got this far, 


With 
set FilteredMonths as
 [Date].[Calendar].[Month].Members
 
Member PyMonthSales as
    GENERATE(FilteredMonths, FilteredMonths.CURRENT.ITEM(0).NAME, ", ")
select 
PyMonthSales on Columns
FROM
(
Select {
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[5], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[4]
} on Columns
From    [Adventure Works]
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up a bit messy!!

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].x AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      Generate
      (
        {
          [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[5]
         ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[4]
        }
       ,{
          ParallelPeriod
          (
            [Date].[Calendar].[Month]
           ,1
           ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
          )
        }
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  x ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The thing I kept forgetting was the curly brackets around the `ParallelPeriod` section - without those an exception is raised because Generate always wants a `SET` as its second argument.